# C++ pointer creation and assignment inside the function

Tags: c++, pointers, variable-assignment, new-operator

What is the difference between `*p_address= new int(2)` and the assignment via &  `p_address = &value` considering that both examples take place inside the function?
For example:
I've got the int pointer *original_pointer. I pass its address to the function. Inside the function I create an int pointer which points to the int value of 2. Then I assign the pointer (which is created inside the function) to the *original_pointer. When I **cout** the *original_pointer outside the function, it returns -858993460, while inside the function it returns the value of 2.
However, when I use **new** to create a pointer inside the function, the value of *original_pointer inside and outside of the function is the same.
Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        void assign_(const int**);
        char* tmp = " ";
        int const *original_pointer;
        assign_(&original_pointer);
        cout << "the address of original_pointer is " << original_pointer << endl;
        cout << "the value of original_pointer is " << *original_pointer << endl;
        cin >> tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}
void assign_( int const **addr) {
    int* p_value;
    int value = 2;
    p_value = &value;
    *addr = p_value;
    //*addr = new RtFloat(2.0);   // If I create the pointer this way the value of *addr is the same with *original_pointer
    cout << "the adress of *addr inside the function is " << *addr << endl;
    cout << "the value of **addr inside the function is " << **addr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*p_address= new int(2)` Allocates memory for <strike>2 ints</strike> one int (with the value 2) which "lives" until you delete it.

`p_address = &value` just sets p_address to the address of a local variable which becomes invalid as soon as the function exits (as you've seen).

Comment: new int(2) doesn't allocate 2 ints. new int[2] does.

Comment: @BenjyKessler D'oh. You're right. Will edit to correct.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `*p_address= new int(2)` and the assignment via `&p_address = &value;` Is that in the first case the value pointed to by `p_address` is on the heap and in the second case it is on the stack. This means that the lifetime of the value pointed to by `p_address` in the first case is until it is deleted and in the second case it is only alive until value goes out of scope.

Comment: *p_address= new int(2) 
is a actually a dynamic memory allocation integers on the heap memory. The program creates memory on heap. This basically means that addresses will remain valid till 1. Delete[] operator is used explicitly by program.2. The process execution stops. When this happens the OS will reallocate the memory to some other process. Most modern OS do this. p_address = &value is basically assigning  the address of a variable to the pointer. This gets allocated on the stack. This means the variable will only be valid as long as it is within a scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `int value = 2;` it is created on the stack. Once the function returns the variable is automatically deallocated.

When you use `*p_address= new int;` the memory is allocated on the heap. it is not automatically deallocated. so even after the function returns that memory is there.